# Read utf-8 character from byte stream

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, utf8-decode

Given a stream of bytes (generator, file, etc.) how can I read a single `utf-8` encoded character?

- This operation must consume the bytes of that character from the stream.
- This operation must not consume any bytes of the stream that exceed the first character.
- This operation should succeed on any Unicode character.

I could approach this by rolling my own `utf-8` decoding function but I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel since I'm sure this functionality must already be used elsewhere to parse `utf-8` strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the stream in a [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) with `encoding='utf8'`, then call `.read(1)` on it.

This is assuming you started with a [`BufferedIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase) or something duck-type compatible with it (i.e. has a `read()` method).  If you have a generator or iterator, you may need to adapt the interface.

Example:

```
from io import TextIOWrapper

with open('/path/to/file', 'rb') as f:
  wf = TextIOWrapper(f, 'utf-8')
  wf._CHUNK_SIZE = 1  # Implementation detail, may not work everywhere

  wf.read(1) # gives next utf-8 encoded character
  f.read(1)  # gives next byte
```

Comment: Does `TextIOWrapper` do any buffering (thereby consuming bytes exceeding the first character)?  If I take a file `f` and wrap it `wrapped = TextIOWrapper(f, 'utf-8')`, calling `wrapper.read(1)` followed by `f.read(1)` reads a byte that is much further into the stream than the byte immediately following the utf-8 character.

Comment: @arcyqwerty: `TextIOWrapper` reads 2k bytes at a time (`_CHUNK_SIZE`). It consumes more bytes than necessary for the first character.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to get raw bytes from the wrapper `TextIOWrapper`?

Comment: In that case it seems to violate `This operation must not consume any bytes of the stream that exceed the first character.`  Is there a workaround to disable buffering?

Comment: @arcyqwerty: set `_CHUNK_SIZE=1`?

Comment: I should probably note that `_CHUNK_SIZE` is an implementation detail which might break in a future version of Python.  Caveat emptor.